# How can I run django using apache2?

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to run django on apache2 using mod_wsgi, but when I'm trying to connect "locatoka.ru" I get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."

My actions:
I added to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/local/Cellar/mod_wsgi/3.2/libexec/mod_wsgi.so
```

changed httpd.conf

```
WSGIScriptAlias /  /Users/Loginov/Desktop/project/project/wsgi.py

<VirtualHost locatoka.ru:80>

ServerName locatoka.ru
ServerAlias www.locatoka.ru

DocumentRoot "/Users/Loginov/Desktop/project"
<Directory /Users/Loginov/Desktop/project/project>
<Files wsgi.py>
    Order deny,allow
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>


</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I'm using Mac OS X El Capitan and Python3.

Comment: You should put the WSGIScriptAlias inside the VirtualHost section.

Comment: But also note there's no need to use Apache to run your project on your laptop in development; use the built-in dev server.

Comment: Also, are you sure locatoka.ru resolves to your Mac?

Comment: For a start, change ``<VirtualHost locatoka.ru:80>`` to ``<VirtualHost *:80>``. What you have will not work.

Comment: You will have other problems as you aren't setting up the Python module search path so that mod_wsgi will know where you project is. Make sure you review the Django documentation on how to use mod_wsgi at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ Some aspects of that doc are out of date though around use of Python virtual environments, so ensure you also read http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

Comment: Finally, using mod_wsgi development is perfectly fine, although if you are doing that, is suggested you avoid configuring Apache yourself and use mod_wsgi-express instead. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: And whatever you do, don't use mod_wsgi 3.2. That is way way out of date.